# Define and use custom SCSS in Next.JS based on condition

Tags: sass

Let's say I want to have a multi-tenant next.js application. I'm using some default SCSS theme, but I would like to customize it based on the tenant. By customize I mean override some variables of the default theme based on tenant. For example:

- Tenant A will use primary color **red**
- Tenant B will use primary color **green**
- Both tenants will use the default theme (where the primary color will be overridden)

I'll have some identifier of the tenant (id) stored in the cookies for example, which I plan to retrieve during runtime.

So preferably, I would like to use multiple files with the following structure:

tenantA.scss, tenantB.scss, global.scss.

Example of tenantA.scss:

```css
$kendo-color-primary: red;
```

Example of global.scss:

```css
$tenantId: 1; /* somehow retrieve an ID (if even possible) */

@if $tenantId == 1 {
    /* import tenantA.scss variables that'll override kendo-theme-material vars */
} @else if $tenantId == 2 {
    /* import tenantB.scss variables that'll override kendo-theme-material vars */
}

@import '@progress/kendo-theme-material/dist/all.scss'; // Import default theme
```

However, I wasn't able to directly import the files inside the condition (was getting compile error). How can I properly code my solution? Is this even possible this way or is there a better way to do it? Should I maybe handle it in javascript code (my next.js app) and import specific styles based on tenant id? If so, how?

Appreciate any help.